# How to share database properties in Maven 3 multi modules projects?

Tags: maven

Let's assume there are 2 applications. The POM hierarchy might look like this:

```
   parent
   --> system A
   --> system B
```

Both systems are supposed to be able to connect to the *same database*.

Each system has 2 profiles: *Development* (embedded DB) and *Production* (MySQL).

**How can I use Maven to share the database connection information (user, path, driver etc.) for each profile ACROSS BOTH systems** (I'm using resource filtering)**?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the properties for those information in the appropriate profile.

Comment: do you mean in each system individually (redundancy?) or in the parent pom (I thought profiles don't inherit) ?

Comment: Define the profile in the root pom and the set properties will be used in the derived project (of course only if you using a multimodule build).

Comment: argh - pressed the wrong arrow - then SO said it's in "maintanance" and now I can't change the vote "unless the answer is edited"

Comment: hm: "You last voted on this answer 3 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited"

Answer (score 2):

Take care when deciding where database connection information will be stored. While it's ok to store driver and url in pom.xml (so this info probably goes to source repository and can be accessed by anyone who is granted access to the source), username and password should not be exposed usually. So they are better specified in settings.xml. This is especially important in your case, when you work with production database.
Nice explanation can be found [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-tips-tricks.html)